# Qt, send UDP through VPN(Hamachi)

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp

I`m writing application, which send voice from one computer to other. I have simple implementation of "sender"

```
VoiceSender::VoiceSender(QAudioFormat &format, QString ip){
    input = new QAudioInput(format);
    QUdpSocket* socket = new QUdpSocket();
    socket->connectToHost(ip, 14433);
    input->start(socket);
}
```

Just get all data from mic and send it as UDP to specified IP.

In the other side I have program, which get all data received by UDP, and play it by audio system

```
Interlocutor::Interlocutor(QAudioFormat &format){
    socket = new QUdpSocket();
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 14433);
    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
        if (!info.isFormatSupported(format))
            format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    output = new QAudioOutput(format);
    device = output->start();
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(playData()));
}

void Interlocutor::playData()
{
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray data;
        data.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(data.data(), data.size());
        device->write(data.data(), data.size());
    }
}
```

If both computers locating in the local network this works well, i can transfer my voice between computers. I tried to run it in the VPN. For it I run Hamachi in both computers, and got nothing. Slot playData() is never called. I run Wireshark and seen that computer get UDP packages, but Qt doesnt. What should I do to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your app connected to listen to 14433 port successfully? Have your checked your firewall? Do you flush the data from sender?

Comment: No, i dont sure that my app connected to listen 14433 successfully, i doesn`t know how i can do it. If firewall will block, Wireshark will see the packages? I think firewall does not block, because in local network all works

Comment: Now I choose "Home" network type in Windows 7. And it is work! Problem in firewall?

Comment: Yes, most of all, you should add the exception to your program. I will add this to the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of the QUdpSocket::bind function.

bool [QUdpSocket::bind](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html#bind) ( const QHostAddress & address, quint16 port )

> On success, the functions returns true and the socket enters
>   BoundState; otherwise it returns false.

```
if (!socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 14433))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(0, "Error", "Binding Failed");
}
```

If binding is failed check if firewall is not blocking you or this port is not used by another application.

Comment: Binding is not failed